# Selecionando parte de um data frame e salvando em loop

Tags: r

tenho um data frame de mais de 1000 linhas e duas colunas (col1 e col2). Como faço para selecionar n data frames (subconjuntos do data frame original) tomando por base a coluna 2 (apenas os elementos iguais) por meio de um loop e, seguinda, salvar os n data.frames (df1, df2,...dfn) em um diretório tb no loop?

Comment: Por favor, disponibilize um [exemplo mínimo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Realize um [tour] no site, após isso veja [ask], ajudará a todos que querem lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria algo assim, no exemplo considerando o data.frame `mtcars` que já está disponível no R.

O `walk` é uma espécie de loop que não retorna nenhum resultado. Com este código estou pedindo que para cada elemento do vetor `distintos`, o R filtre o data.frame pela variável `cyl` e depois escreva esse novo `data.frame` em um arquivo chamado `var=valor_utilizado.csv"` no diretorio `meudir`.

```
library(purrr)
distintos <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
walk(distintos, ~mtcars[mtcars$cyl == .x,] %>% 
       write.csv(paste0("meudir/var=", .x, ".csv"))
)
```

Isso criará 3 arquivos, um para cada valor distinto da variável `cyl`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Usando também o `mtcars` com a coluna `cyl`, segue exemplo fazendo um loop com o `for`:

```
for(i in seq_along(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
  write.csv(subset(mtcars, cyl == unique(mtcars$cyl)[[i]]), paste0("df", i,".csv"))
```

Como resultado temos os 3 `csv`s:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]